# bash: convert date from to unix timestamp changes timestamp

Tags: bash, xen, shell, date, convert

Running the following command at the xen-servers (either DOM0 or DOMU) at $company gives me a negativ number, on every other system zero (0) (even in my cygwin).

```
date -d "1970-01-01T00:00:00" "+%s"
```

`$TZ` is unset, `/etc/localtime` is the same file as `/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC`

date is in version 8.12 from the GNU coreutils. What went wrong here? What additional informations may be needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $TZ is unset and /etc/localtime is UTC then why are you using timezone T (Tango) in the date command?

On my system I have a localtime of EDT.

```
# date
Wed Mar 18 12:39:03 EDT 2015

# date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00" "+%s"
18000
```

If I force it to Tango then I get a negative number:

```
# date -d "1970-01-01T00:00:00" "+%s"
-25200
```

If I change my timezone to UTC it will work as expected:

```
# export TZ=UTC
# date
Wed Mar 18 16:41:23 UTC 2015
# date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00" "+%s"
0
```

from the date man page:

```
DATE STRING
       The  --date=STRING  is  a  mostly  free  format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42
   -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating calendar
   date,  time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indi-
   cates the beginning of the day.  The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here but is
   fully described in the info documentation.
```

As you can see it is a  "mostly free format human readable date", it will pick up the timezone from anywhere it sees fit.  It is very easy to test it.

For example:

```
# date
Wed Mar 18 13:05:42 EDT 2015
```

now with Tango time:

```
[root@wailea ~]# date -d "2015-3-18T13:05:42" 
Wed Mar 18 02:05:42 EDT 2015
```

now with Tango time at the end:

```
[root@wailea ~]# date -d "2015-3-18 13:05:42 T" 
Wed Mar 18 02:05:42 EDT 2015
```

now Zulu time:

```
[root@wailea ~]# date -d "2015-3-18Z13:05:42" 
Wed Mar 18 09:05:42 EDT 2015
```

I think you can see the point.  If you are not familiar with military timezones here is the list:  http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/military

You can also try to use zdump to see if your zone file is not really what you are expecting:

```
Zdump prints the current time in each zonename named on the command line.

# zdump /etc/localtime
/etc/localtime  Wed Mar 18 21:21:04 2015 EDT
```

Comment: My reading of the info pages for date is that "T" and " " can be used equivalently to separate date and time. I don't see anything (in section 28.5) saying that "T" implies special handling of the time but you're obviously getting different behaviour. Have you got a reference for the "tango" behaviour? I get the same with T and space (using UTC or Europe/London which is local timezone).

Comment: I updated my answer but just to be clear, I am working with Centos/RedHat systems.

Comment: also test your zonename file with zdump as explained above, maybe it will reveal that somebody renamed the original UTC file with something else

Comment: Ok, zdump gives the right UTC timezone. But I would never think off that date can't parse ISO-8601 in the right way -_-

Comment: @PaulHaldane The info page for date at those systems doesn't state anything about ' ' and 'T' as seperator or any seperator at all. Seems like date 8.12 is just too plain old.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the date and time in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) format, you need to append a `Z` if you want to force it to be handled as UTC:

```
$ date -d "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" "+%s"
0
```

Alternatively, you can use a UTC offset of either `+0` or `-0` instead of `Z`.

Comment: At least with date 8.12 this gives a »date: invalid date `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'«

Comment: Must be new, then. I was testing with 8.23.